# Cannot find module "./app.module.ngfactory"

Tags: android, angular, typescript, npm, ionic2

I updated Ionic from RC1 to RC3 following the documentation instructions and after that I can't run my app properly in Android using `ionic run android` or `ionic build android`. Previewing with `ionic serve` and .apk build works properly, but when I run the app in my device or in an emulator, it shows the splashscreen and after a blank WebView. When I debug via `chrome://inspect`, it shows in console the following error:

```
main.js:7 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./app.module.ngfactory"
```

I made a backup of the project folder before the update, when my app was working properly, and the code is the same (no changes during the upgrade), and the `app.module.ts`, `main.dev.ts` and `main.prod.ts` seems fine. 
I tried remove .tmp and node-modules folder and run `npm install` again, but the error persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-find-module-app-module-ngfactory/72832/3

The newest version of typescript caused the error for me.

Comment: Thanks! Just downgrade TypeScript to 2.0.10 in package.json, delete node-modules folder and rerun `npm install` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had an import problem with NGTranslate.

See here [Ionic Forum Post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ts-cannot-find-module-app-module-ngfactory/64968)